# Is there a weather website that i can scrape given a city name?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am in a recruitment process for a small company and received a weird homework assignment.
They asked me to display weather metadata such as windspeed and temperature for any location in the world **without using any API**.

So, the only option I see now is scraping a HTML website. I didn't find any website that can be **scraped** with only a city name. The only one that is easy to scrape but needs a country code is wunderground.com .

Does anybody know a website like this ? Or maybe can recommend another approach to this problem.

I'm using Python's BeautifulSoup library, but of course I will use any other language/technology you'll recommend.

Thx ;)

Comment: Why not API? What about [OpenWeather](https://openweathermap.org/api)? Anyway, you can scrap it using the URL ```https://openweathermap.org/find?q=city_name```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like accdias' solution in his comments, but to look at other options, you can simulate browsing the wunderweather site with selenium:

Also note, I included a package called `choice` found [here](https://pypi.org/project/choice/) to install.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import choice

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/'

city = input('Type a city: ')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_name('query').send_keys(city)

time.sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
possible_cities = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'ui-autocomplete-term'})

choose_city = [ x.parent.text for x in possible_cities ]
city = choice.Menu(choose_city).ask()

driver.find_element_by_name('query').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
driver.find_element_by_name('query').send_keys(Keys.DELETE)

driver.find_element_by_name('query').send_keys(city)
driver.find_element_by_name('query').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
temp = soup.find('div', {'class':'condition-data'})
wind = soup.find('div', {'class':'condition-wind'})

deg = temp.find('span',{'class':'ng-star-inserted'}).text.split()[-1]
hi = temp.find('span',{'class':'hi'}).text
low = temp.find('span',{'class':'lo'}).text
current = temp.find('span',{'class':'wu-value wu-value-to'}).text

wdesc = wind.find('p',{'class':'ng-star-inserted'}).text.strip()

print ('%s\nHi: %s%s Low: %s%s Current: %s%s\n%s' %(city, hi,deg, low,deg, current,deg, wdesc))


driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Type a city: paris
Make a choice:
 0: Paris, France 
 1: Paris, TX 
 2: Paris, TN 
 3: Paris, KY 
 4: Paris, IL 
 5: Paris, AR 
 6: Parish, NY 
 7: Paris, MI 
 8: Paris, MO 
 9: Paris, OH 

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 0

Paris, France 
Hi: 44°F Low: 32°F Current: 43F
Gusts 5 mph
```

Comment: amazing, you really helped !